# How to enable property change for data binding?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

Suppose I have VM which has implemented INotifyPropertyChange:

```
public class MyViewModel{
  public MyClass{get;set;}
  ...
}
```

but plain class MyClass not implemented INotifyPropertyChange, It only hold some properties, like:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
        }
        public string P1 { get; set; }
    ... 
    }
```

in xaml, DataContext is MyViewModel. I set binding like:

```
Text = "{Binding MyClass.P1}"
```

Then in MyViewModel constructor, I set up instance of MyClass and fire property change like

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyClass");
```

but the value of P1 does not display in UI. How to implement something like this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyClass.P1") in this case?

Comment: `public MyClass{get;set;}` won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the class that owns the property.

If you can't make that class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you should create a separate ViewModel class that wraps it and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.  The best option would be to either wrap this value in your ViewModel, which would allow you to raise the `PropertyChanged` event directly on the ViewModel.

However, if this is not an option for one reason or another, the other option is to call:

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
```

This will refresh *all* of the bindings on the View, including `MyClass.P1`.  This is not always a great solution from a performance standpoint, however, as it forces a full binding refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an event with a name following this template:

```
public event EventHandler <PropertyName>Changed;
public event EventHandler P1Changed;
```

The binding will "auto-detect" the `P1Changed` event and use it for data binding.

All you need to do is raise the `P1Changed` event when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property of type MyClass to your ViewModel. In the setter of your property is where you would call RaisePropertyChanged().

For example,

```
    public MyClass SomeName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SomeName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._SomeName)
            {
                this._SomeName = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SomeName");
            }
        }
    }

    private MyClass _SomeName;
```